# POSIX - rebuild multiline strings with awk and feed them to xargs

Tags: shell, awk, posix, aix

I have a file where each record starts with `./` and has a superfluous linefeed at the end:

```
./a
b/
./c
d"
./
e

f
/
./
g

h'
```

What I want to do is:

**1.** rebuild the records that don't end with `/`

**2.** output them, escaped for `xargs`

The expected output (when displayed with bash `printf '%q\n'`) should be:

```bash
$'./c\nd"'
$'./\ng\n\nh\'\n'
```

Here's what I tried:

```bash
{
    cat input.txt
    echo ./
} |
awk -F '^[.]/' '
    function xargs_escape(s) {
        gsub(/[[:space:]\047"]/, "\\\\&", s);
        return s;
    }
    {
        if ( NF == 2 ) {
            if ( NR > 1 && record ~ /[^/]$/ )
                print xargs_escape(record)
            record = $0
        } else
            record = record "\n" $0
    }
' |
xargs bash -c 'printf %q\\n "$@"'
```

But what I get is:

```bash
$'./\ng\n\nh\'\n'
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

###### UPDATE

Sorry, the problem wasn't in the `awk` but in the `bash -c`:

```bash
... | xargs bash -c 'printf %q\\n "$0" "$@"'
```

Now it works as expected:

```
$'./c\nd"'
$'./\ng\n\nh\'\n'
```

**Should I delete the question?**